# How many the binary sequences of length n such there are no two zeros next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

I come up with:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\left \lfloor{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right \rfloor}{{n-i+1}\choose{i}}$$

Which I think is true but is there a way to write it not as a sum?

Comment: Try the Fibonacci numbers ...

Comment: I mean to  the number of components of the sum doesn't  depend on $n$

Comment: You can use inclusion-exclusion

Comment: @Mickey I see but what should I include/exclude?

Comment: Hint: if your number is $f(n)$, show that $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ by conditioning on the first member of the sequence.

Comment: $r_1=n\cdot(1),m\cdot(0)$|||||
$r_2=n+m\cdot(1),n\cdot(0)$|||||
$r_3=2n+m\cdot(1),n+m\cdot(0)$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ok but How to even come up with the idea of using the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Conditioning on the first term is often a good strategy.  Once you get the recursion, you recognize it as the Fibonacci recursion and then you're done.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1,2,3,...$ the answer is $2$, $3$, $5$, $8$, etc. Maybe a well-known sequence?

Comment: OEIS says that there are 825 well-known sequences with 2, 3, 5, 8 $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.